# How can I get rid of the VS Code warning of "Seriver[x] disconnected unexpectedly"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I ran into this warning (see pictures as I run Python multiprocessing to fire up multiple cores (almost all the core available). After I clicked cancel. I will see the second error message which says failed to launch debugger fora child processes.

The code will finish running and produce correct results. But VS code will generate multiple warning and laying on top of the entire VS code, which need to be manually click off.

Do we know the proper way to prevent this from happening?

Some relevent post I found. As I am investigating, I will keep updating this post.

- https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/712

[image: Seriver[x] disconnected unexpectedly]
[image])

Comment: look like a problem in your debug adapter for your language, or the debugger itself, the part that interfaces with the adapter

Comment: @rioV8 I think you guess correctly!